# jQuery - Open image parent link in another div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a carousel that when an image is clicked, Id like to take the source of the image and open it up in another div on the page, 'big-image'

```
$('.gallery-viewport-ext ul li a img').on('click', function () {
     alert($(this).parent('a').attr('src');)
 return false;  
});
```

Im trying to just alert the src at first only Im sure I must have done something wrong?

```
<div id="tabs1-ext">
<section class="gallery-viewport-ext">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="_includes/images/slide-1.jpg"><img src="_includes/images/slide-1.jpg" alt="image" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="_includes/images/slide-2.jpg"><img src="_includes/images/slide-2.jpg" alt="image" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="_includes/images/slide-3.jpg"><img src="_includes/images/slide-3.jpg" alt="image" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="_includes/images/slide-1.jpg"><img src="_includes/images/slide-1.jpg" alt="image" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="_includes/images/slide-2.jpg"><img src="_includes/images/slide-2.jpg" alt="image" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="_includes/images/slide-3.jpg"><img src="_includes/images/slide-3.jpg" alt="image" /></a></li>
        </ul>
        <a id="simplePrevious"><img src="_includes/images/larr.png" alt="Left Arrow" /></a>
        <a id="simpleNext"><img src="_includes/images/rarr.png" alt="Right Arrow" /></a>
    </section>
```

```
<div class="big-image"><</div>
```

Im new to jQuery so excuse my naivity!

Comment: Maybe there's a reason for this, but I don't understand why you would target `.gallery-viewport-ext ul li a img` and then basically right after that you target the parent `.gallery-viewport-ext ul li a` with your `$(this).parent('a')`. Why not just target the `a` for the click event from the get-go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use link instead of img

```
$('.gallery-viewport-ext ul li a').on('click', function () {
     alert($(this).attr('href'));
     var $bigImg = $("<img />").attr("src", $(this).attr('href'));
     $(".big-image").html($bigImg);
     event.preventDefault();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `attr('href')`, instead of `src`, also, remove the semicolon after `attr()`

```
alert($(this).parent('a').attr('href'))
```

EDIT:

```
$('.gallery-viewport-ext ul li a img').on('click', function () {
     $('.big-image').html($(this).parent().html());
     return false;  
});
```

OR

```
$('.gallery-viewport-ext ul li a').on('click', function () {
     $('.big-image').html($(this).html());
     return false;  
});
```

Comment: Im actually trying to open the image in another div, the alert was to test I could call the source correctly thanks @SiGanteng

Comment: Yes that worked thanks @SiGanteng, now Id like to open it in another div however, thats where im stuck

Answer (score 0):

The following will add the image to the big div.

```
$('.gallery-viewport-ext ul li a img').on('click', function (event) {
 event.preventDefault();
 $('.bigimage').html('').append($('<img</img>').attr('src',$(this).parent('a').attr('href')));
});
```

Comment: Im actually trying to open the image in another div, the alert was to test I could call the source correctly thanks @Senthil Kumar

Comment: ah okay, as others have said, you just have to use 'href' instead of 'src' and take care of the semicolon inside the alert.

Comment: @Liam updated the answer to show the image in the big div, hope this helps.